# GDB resuming execution after the exception cause is fixed

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Assume I have a program with a statement at **line 5** which creates an arithmetic exception: division by zero.

When I `run` the program in GDB I get something like this:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x... in ... at prog.c:5
```

At that point, I change the divisor variable to a nonzero value using
`set var b=1` and then try to "resume" from the same statement that got the exception.

Using the command `continue` gives the following:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
The program no longer exists.
```

So the correct way is to use (instead of the `continue` command) a command like `jump 5` which works as expected.

Is there any other *easier* GDB command to do this *with no need to specify the line number where the program got the exception*? There may be more than one statement in the line, so addressing with line number cannot be feasible all the times.

I couldn't find anything related to this in GDB Documentation.

Comment: In fact after the program is actually terminated I am surprised that even `jump` works. Once the program is terminated - there is nowhere to jump. I think it is rather *restarting* the program from line 5, which might lead to weird results.

Comment: No. I used the `jump` command ___instead of___ the `continue` command. That is: (1) get the exception, (2) fix the divisor (to nonzero value), and (3) `jump` to the same statement containing the division.

Comment: Ah, I see. Misread the sequence of the events.

Comment: Maybe the [signal 0](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_113.html#SEC118) command will do what you want.

Comment: Yes @MarkPlotnick. That seems to do the trick!

Comment: OK. So, Craig Estey's answer does a great job at explaining all the things that can prevent a simple `set var` command from sufficiently repairing the operands. If you can fix the operands of the machine instruction that caused the fault - that might mean setting non-obvious registers and memory instead of `set var` - then you can type `signal 0` to retry the instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MarkPlotnick commented in my question, `signal 0` is the answer I was looking for (subject to all caveats mentioned in @CraigEstey's answer):

```
$ gdb -silent ./a.out  ## Program compiled with disabled optimizations!
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) l 1,20
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   void bol (int a, int b)
4   {
5     printf("%d / %d = %d\n", a, b, a/b);
6   } /* bol */
7   
8   int main (void)
9   {
10    int x, y;
11    for (x=170, y=6; x>-170; x-=30, y-=2)
12      bol(x, y);
13  } /* main */
(gdb) r
Starting program: [...]/a.out 
170 / 6 = 28
140 / 4 = 35
110 / 2 = 55

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x000055555555515f in bol (a=80, b=0) at prog.c:5
5     printf("%d / %d = %d\n", a, b, a/b);
(gdb) set var b=1
(gdb) sig 0
Continuing with no signal.
80 / 1 = 80
50 / -2 = -25
20 / -4 = -5
-10 / -6 = 1
-40 / -8 = 5
-70 / -10 = 7
-100 / -12 = 8
-130 / -14 = 9
-160 / -16 = 10
[Inferior 1 (process 7088) exited normally]
(gdb) q
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach *can't* work in the general case, particularly if optimization is on.

What you did just *happened* to work for your specific line/case. We can't tell too much because you *didn't* post the code.

The variable `b` starts in memory (either on the stack or in global memory).

At some point, it *may* end up in an FP register (e.g. for x86, `xmm*`).

So, when you do: `set var b = 1` are you setting the memory location or the `xmm` register?

Even assuming only one statement per line, when you do `jump` you are restarting the *statement* (which can consist of multiple asm *instructions*).

What other things do we have to do to ensure that all *other* values (register, memory, etc.) are in the pre-statement/pre-instruction state?

With optimization, the value of `b` may have been cached in an `xmm` register by a *prior* statement, and the one you're doing the `jump` to may *not* reload it [from memory]

What you want to do is restart the *instruction*. At that point, the 2nd arg to the instruction may be an `xmm` register or a memory location. How can we tell which one?

Also, if you have (e.g.):

```
a = get_a_value();
// several more statements ...
a /= b;  // line 5
```

Then, we assume `a` is in (e.g.) `xmm0` [and `b` is in `xmm1`]. The following is pseudo-asm:

```
fdiv %xmm0,%xmm1 // a /= b
```

What does the [pseudo] `fdiv` instruction do to the value of `a` in `%xmm0`? After the instruction is the value of `a` still intact or does `%xmm0` now have a partial/garbage value? The value that is in `%xmm0` after the failed instruction is architecture dependent. It the value is trashed, how do we determine the original/correct value to put back into `%xmm0`?

How many *prior* statements must be executed to restore the correct value of `a`?

You may have to disassemble the "offending" instruction and change the value of 2nd argument. If it's a memory location, change that. If it's an `xmm*` register, you'll have to change that.

And, you'll have to determine what has to be done to restore the `a` value (*wherever* it is residing).

The remediation that you want to do needs to be handled at the instruction level. Statement level is too coarse grained.

The reason that you can't find documentation on this is that what you're doing won't work too well in the general case and is contorting `gdb`.

`gdb` is designed so you can trap such an exception, determine what the bug in your program is, fix the *source* code, rebuild and rerun.

C [and/or machine code] isn't designed to allow such dynamic patch and restart from a prior point [in a debugger console] as you may have in an interpreted language such as Java/Perl/Python.

Comment: To make long story short, you say that it is no advisable, feasible, or even sometimes possible to restart such a program (that I described) after an exception? Yes, I believe that some of your comments are true, but my question was for a program compiled with optimization disabled and the statement at line 5 had no side effects, except assigning the result to another variable. If optimization is enabled, any `set var ...` may not work as expected anyway.

Comment: I just want to point out that there are exceptions. For example, I've written code that explicitly uses an opcode that will cause an undefined operation exception so that the code can be patched at run time to be appropriate for the particular CPU configuration being used. But the code was explicitly designed to trigger the exception in a known context and the inline function that triggered the exception was handed-coded in assembly.

Answer (score -1):

> Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
> 0x... in ... at prog.c:5
> At that point, I change the divisor variable to a nonzero value using set var b=1 and then try to "resume" from the same statement that got the exception.
> Using the command continue gives the following:...

If the program received an exception, this means that the program has finished (better said, has been finished by the kernel) so you cannot continue.

To do what you pretend, you need to intervene **before** the program crashes.  So, put a break point just before the program has to make the division, so the debugger stops the program before it crashes, then change the divisor variable (with the `set var...` command), then let it continue, and observe that it doesn't crash.

```
set br 5
run
set var b = 5
cont
```

and now everything goes fine.

If your program ends without notifying the debugger, it is notified by the kernel anyway of program termination... but once the program has terminated, there's no chance to run it from the state it had (not even if you have a core to do post-mortem debugging)  The core from an exception  is not continuable, as the program has died and lost the control.  The debugger doesn't know from where to start it running again, because it is in bad state.

But believe me, the best is to check why the divisor is zero and avoid this **in the program itself** and not to have to run the debugger each time you want to pass the division point to change the divisor so the program doesn't fail.

Comment: "_If the program received an exception, this means that the program has finished (better said, has been finished by the kernel) so you cannot continue._" That is simply wrong.